# Not an answer flag declined due to review

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, review-queues, declined-flags

I flagged an answer as *not an answer* and my flag got declined because i need to first review ?

> [image]

if my flag will decline no matter its right or wrong , than why there is option for *not an answer*

and if i need to review that post first than why review link shows all post instead of that particular post.

so it would be easy to review post , if it have review link with share,edit,flag link

Comment: Did you manage to flag it the first time? I think that's just a warning you just had a declined flag, which was probably something else and might even be a flag that was hanging around a while that was just declined.

Comment: oh its my bad sorry for wasting everyone's time , you are right :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you misunderstand the message: it does not say that your last flag was declined because you need to first review, but it says that your last flag was declined and the dialog asks you to first go to your flags page and review the declined flag; check out why it was declined.